# Why can't i use __construct methods in controllers in OpenCart with vqmod

Tags: php, opencart

I have tried adding just an empty `__construct` method to a module controller.

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/rodebutik.dk/public_html/wb/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 16

Line 16:

```
public function __get($key) {
    return $this->registry->get($key);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why You shouldn't use `__construct()` methods... Please, provide us with the code, an **empty** `__construct()` cannot produce such an error.

Comment: I would guess that the Registry instance is passed via the the object you're extending. When you redefine and empty construct, it's no longer set - hence the error.

Comment: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/controller.php#L5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely explanation: the original constructor was setting up the `$this->registry` object. You are overriding the constructor, which now does not set up that object anymore. Hence: you error out when the code is trying to use the expected object which is not there.

If you override a constructor, you should/need to invoke the original one as well:

```
public function __construct(...) {
    parent::__construct(...);

    // new code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a constructor in controller or model like this way.

```
class ModelMyModel extends Model {
   public function __construct($params) {
      parent::__construct($params);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor like this, same for Model also you can use, by passing parameter.

```
class ControllerCommonDashboard extends Controller {

    public function __construct($params) {
        parent::__construct($params);
    }
}
```